# Htacess Rewrite Rule - Doesn't work without Trailing Slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have the following Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)(\.php)?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?shop=$1&page=index [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ index.php?shop=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Everything seems to work great, if I go to domain.com/shop/  then it works fine and shows the index.  If I go to domain.com/shop/about.php then it works perfect.

The only thing that does not work is when I go to domain.com/shop without a trailing slash, it does not display anything I get a bunch of errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  It's probably something super simple to add to my code but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second rule, add `?` after trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?shop=$1&page=index [NC,L,QSA]
```

That will make trailing `/` optional

Answer (score 2):

I usually end my rules with `/?$` meaning string ending with one slash or no shash.